# MySql - Select some characters after certain word and add it to another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table which include 2 column: title and param, the values are like the following:

-title: `Teaching`

-params:

```
{"ufield926":"34","ufield927":"Sud","ufield928":"Ara","ufield929":"Mecca",
 "ufield930":"1\/1\/1983","ufield933":"011","ufield934":"Mub",
 "ufield943":"SU\/HI\/14","ufield944":"Average","ufield946":"Female"}
```

I want to extract the code after `"ufield943":` which is `SU\/HI\/14` only and concatenate it with the value in title column to be like the following:

```
Teaching (SU\/HI\/14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select *,
       substring(
         params,
         locate('ufield943', params) + 12,
         locate('ufield944', params) - locate('ufield943', params) - 15
       )
from tbl;
```

But I assumed that `ufield944` occurs directly after `ufield943`.

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dDVKktpF2PRLaDx8kuc4Dj/0)

Comment: Thanks, The query successfully get the intended code, but I am little confused how to concatenate the code with the title column in order to have the following:

Teaching (SU\/HI\/14)

Comment: Get an Error ER_NO_TABLES_USED after running the following: 

update tbl set title = CONCAT_WS(title,' ', '(' , (select *,
       substring(
         params,
         locate('ufield943', params) + 12,
         locate('ufield944', params) - locate('ufield943', params) - 15
       )),')');

Comment: Any Idea how Fix That?, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value in `params` is JSON, so your best solution might be to look at MySQL [JSON support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

I'm not familiar with MySQL JSON support, if that doesn't work for you I would look at MySQL's [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) and [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to do this:

```
SELECT
    title
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(params, '"ufield943"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"([^"\\]|\\.)+'),
        '^"ufield943"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"', '')
FROM MyTable
```

The regex finds the value regardless of where it is in the json and allows for whitespace in the column (like `"ufield943" : "SU\/HI\/14"`).

Comment: Get an Error ER_NO_TABLES_USED after running the following: 

update tbl set title = CONCAT_WS(title,' ', '(' , (select *, substring( params, locate('ufield943', params) + 12, locate('ufield944', params) - locate('ufield943', params) - 15 )),')');

Any Idea how Fix That?, Thanks

Comment: @AbbasSoliman you've removed the `FROM MyTable` part, so MySQL doesn't understand where `title` and `params` columns are coming from. If you still can't get the `update` statement to work, best to ask a new question on here. That's a different problem than finding the `ufield943` value so it deserves a different question on the site.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, will create new question then